# Can I install software from debian package without internet

Tags: software-installation, debian

This is a silly question but can you install software from debian packages without having an internet connection ?

Comment: Related: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. One of the methods is to use the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

You can also try to install the file via Ubuntu Software/Snap Store application by double clicking on it in file manager (although this usually didn't work for me - but in theory it's supposed to work).

One more method is to use GDebi, it's a GUI installer for `.deb` files. It is my preferred tool to install non-repository packages. But it's not installed by default, so you have to install it first while you **do** have an Internet connection.

However, if the package to be installed has any dependencies, you must resolve them manually and install all dependencies first.

Comment: I have given your answer a best answer and very very thank you sir

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do it by using Gdebi.
Suppose, you have already downloaded a Deb package `software-package-example.deb`.
To install it, open terminal in the same directory where the package is downloaded and type

```
sudo gdebi software-package-example.deb
```

Done.

If Gdebi is not installed, you can run

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Comment: And to run `sudo apt-get install gdebi` you need internet which **defeats the purpose of the question**. The other answer using `dpkg` is the correct one. **No additional software is required**.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. As I can't mark both questions as best, I am giving you a great great thanks in advance